# Retrieving out parameter from stored procedure using ASP.Net MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm trying to retrieve the `OUT` parameter from the procedure by creating `ObjectParameter` variables and assigning it to the `OUT` parameters. I'm assuming the variables will be populated.

But when I try to output it, it's only showing the value as `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter` even though I converted it to string. Is there a property of the `ObjectParameter` that I can get the string value? How do I retrieve the out parameters populated by the stored procedure?

I've also tried this:

```
Debug.WriteLine("get_subcatid: " + (string)get_subcatid.Value);
```

but it's producing an `InvalidCastException` error.

Stored procedure parameters:

```
PROCEDURE getItemSubcat (
    p_itemid        IN    ITEM_MSTR.item_id%TYPE,
    p_catid         IN    ITEM_MSTR.cat_id%TYPE,
    n_subcat_id     OUT   SUBCAT_MSTR.subcat_id%TYPE,
    n_subcat_name   OUT   SUBCAT_MSTR.subcat_name%TYPE        
);
```

Sample code:

```
DBEntities _db = new DBEntities();

int sample_id = 1;
int sample_subcatid = 2;

var get_subcatid = new ObjectParameter("n_subcat_id", typeof(string));
var get_subcatname = new ObjectParameter("n_subcat_name", typeof(string));

_db.getItemSubcat(sample_id, sample_subcatid, get_subcatid, get_subcatname);

Debug.WriteLine("sampleid: " + sample_id);
Debug.WriteLine("sample_subcatid: " + sample_subcatid);
Debug.WriteLine("get_subcatid: " + get_subcatid.ToString());
Debug.WriteLine("get_subcatname: " + get_subcatname.ToString());
```

Output:

```
sampleid: 1
sample_subcatid: 2
get_subcatid: System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter
get_subcatname: System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter
```

Comment: Looking [at the official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) (**highly** recommended!!), I'd say you should inspect the `.Value` property instead of calling the `.ToString()` method .....

Comment: I tried using the `.Value` property but nothing is being displayed. So does that mean I have an error in putting a value in the ObjectParameter?

Comment: In my code `_db.getItemSubcat(sample_id, sample_subcatid, get_subcatid, get_subcatname);`, is this how to populate the `get_sucatid` and `get_subcatname` out parameters?